# how to import data with 'arbitary' format?

Tags: import, data, text

When I want to import data (.txt or .dat) for plotting, I can just use the `Import`. Problem is that, sometimes the data in the files are separated by comma, sometimes they don't. Sometimes they are arranged in columns nicely, sometimes they are just in one line. My usual approach is to 'beautify' the data manually, by making sure that each pair of data occupies one line, and the coordinates are separated by the `tab` key without any comma. This works for a small number of data, and will be impossible for large amount of data.

So my question is, are they any ways to import data regardless of how they are arranged in the data file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) and [`SemanticImport`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SemanticImport.html) can handle many different formats, and each has several options to customize the import.

For a start, check out [Table](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Table.html), [TSV](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/TSV.html) and [CSV](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/CSV.html).

Look at documented `"Table"` options such as `"FieldSeparators"`, `"IgnoreEmptyLines"`, `"RepeatedSeparators"`, `"HeaderLines"`, etc.  These give you quite a but of flexibility.  It is possible to simultaneously allow multiple different field and record separators, e.g. let either tab or comma separate entries within the same file.

`SemanticImport` can additionally take a type specification for each column you are importing.  This helps with certain data formats. It also has a `"Delimiters"` option.  Its return type can be controlled using its third argument (*format*), which is described in the Details section of its documentation page. `SemanticImport` is unfortunately slower than `Import`.

There is also `Read` and [`ReadList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReadList.html).  `ReadList` is very fast, takes type specifications and allows specifying the [`RecordSeparators`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecordSeparators.html).

If none of this helps with your format, please ask a separate, more specific question.

---

Finally: be sure to read the documentation of all of these, *including the Details and Options sections!*.

Comment: `SemanticImport` actually manages to load the data in a nice table format, but is it possible to convert it to a matrix? The main problem I am having is that if I use `Import`, very often it can represents the data in matrix form

Comment: @Physicist Ah, I assume you mean that it returns a Dataset by default.  Please look up `Dataset`.  Please check under the Details section of the SemanticImport documentation where it is explained how to use its third argument ("form") to choose a return format (e.g. list of rows like Import).

Comment: @Physicist You can use `Normal` to convert a `Dataset` to nested lists and associations.  It may actually be `ds[All, Values]` or similar what you need, depending on the type of Dataset.  But better just use the third argument of SemanticImport.

Comment: `Normal` works perfectly for me in this case. thx